# Saving game progress with NSUserDefault: Good or Bad idea?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, nsuserdefaults

I'm working on a game and all progress the user makes will be saved with NSUserDefaults. Is it a good or bad idea???

What are the chances of losing the game saved? Is there a better way to do this?

When the user syncs the device, iTunes will backup NSUserDefaults? So in case the user changes his device he will not lose the progress, he just has to sync the device with iTunes? How safe is it?

GameCenter achievements will be saved with NSUserDefaults as well, in case the user doesn't have an internet connection at the time.

Well, I just wanna know your opinion/experience. All code is working flawless, but I'm afraid the player might lose his progress for some reason.

If anyone wants more details on the code fell free to ask, I can post it here.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 I too have been curious about this and your question helped me allot, although I have checked and been satisfied with `NSUserDefault`, but curiosity leads me to bank on database.. Now there no curiosity any more, many thanks for this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` are synced to iTunes if the user syncs the app. The data is safe as long as the user does not delete the game.

If you need to preserve the data even after the user deletes the game, you may consider saving the data somewhere else (say, Dropbox, own server, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking about storing on my own server, then it would be able to sync the game on multiple devices, for example if the user has an iPhone and an iPad. Any idea how to do this, export NSUserDefaults to a server? No code, just something that I can research would be great.

Comment: You could use iCloud for that backup, just remember the iCloud equivalent of NSUserDefaults is limited to like 64 kb

Comment: Serialize to a JSON dictionary and `POST` it to a script on your server along with the username (if you have accounts). At startup, `GET` from the same URL and return a JSON dictionary object which you deserialize into an `NSDictionary` and import into `NSUserDefaults` manually. Just be wary of the edge cases, e.g when both of a user's devices have the game already running, and one of them updates the settings.. what do you want to do? Continuously sync? Overwrite with whatever settings the current instance has?

Comment: EmilioPelaez, darvids0n: thanks for the answers. iCloud sync would be fantastic, but I will try to make everything on my own server. It is a game, so I would continuously save the data or at least save before the app closes. I would only load when the game opens. If the save game is different (if he opens on a different device with the same login) the app should ask if he want to overwrite the data with the one on the server. Does not sound easy at all to do this, but it will be fantastic. Thanks for the help and ideas guys, I appreciate.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, NSUserDefaults is perfectly safe. The contents are even maintained after a version update of the app.